# VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 (and 17.04) guest with bad resolution

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, screen, display

I have just installed the following ISO in a VirtualBox GUEST on a Windows 10 HOST:

```
ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

EDIT: looks like the same happens with 17.04.

the host is:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
```

VBox version:

[image]

After following the normal Ubuntu install procedure I decided to install the Guest additions, via:

```
Devices -> Insert Guest CD...
```

It opened a terminal window, the installation proceed with no-errors and it said something like "Press enter to close".

After restarting the GUEST OS, I see this and it's only possible use the keyboard as the mouse clicks are broken!:
[image]

And the only solution is to uninstall the Guest Additions via:

```
Open terminal with CTRL + ALT + T
go to the mounted additions disk in /media
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAddtions.run uninstall
```

Does anyone know how to fix that? Is this X11 related?

NOTE: I've also tried installing the guest additions via:

```
sudo apt-get install ...-dkms
```

but that returned errors in the lines of "this module is old".

NOTE: i've also tried going to System -> Additional Drivers and enabling the VBOX driver, but that did not affect the resolution problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling 3D hardware acceleration fixed the small screen problem.

Power down the VM and go to Settings -> Display and uncheck "Enable 3D Acceleration"

I was able to run glmark2 on the Ubuntu Guest and it seems to have decent performance (without swap internal support, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

- Settings > Display > Remote Display
- Check "Enable Server"
- Change the Server Port to anything but 3389, 3390 works for me.
- Open the Windows "Remote Desktop Connection"
- The connection address will be localhost:3390

Disabling 3D hardware acceleration did not fix the problem for me, it caused Ubuntu to boot with a black screen.